# Are there any right hand dominant alternatives to Dvorak keyboard layouts that are about as old as Dvorak?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Dvorak is unique in that it is right hand dominant.

Are there any keyboard layouts that are similar in that way that are about the same age to Dvorak(1936) by August Dvorak?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I do not know about the same age, but Sholes (the inventor of QWERTY) also invented a second layout known as the "Sholes Second Layout", which is right-handed oriented

[image].

This layout was never used commercially, but according to some historians it is the inspiration for Dvorak's keyboard. You can see how the vowels are arranged in the same way, except that they are mirrored

There is an academic paper on [keyboard layouts](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Sholess-final-keyboard-layout-8_fig5_237105161) that tells a bit of this story, but quite honestly it's not much than what I already said: **Sholes created it but never used it**.